# How to integrate CAC card with Windows Login

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, login, windows

Does anyone know how to integrate the DoD CAC card with the Windows Server 2003/2008/2012 Login Process? I want my users to be able to insert the card into the reader and just enter their pin to login to the system. I know its possible to do in Linux but I can't find out how to do it in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best public hint on how to do this is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281245. However for others who need to set this up, that document was not enough for me to get it working.

On a side note there is an excellent step-by-step process available to walk someone through setting this up but it is available only through the US DoD INFOSEC department.